# ajax: match input with a value in an object and identify the id of that object

Tags: arrays, ajax, api, object

I have an array from my API that prints like this:

```
Array [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

// if stringified
[{"id":"0","name":"user1","type":"mf","message":"bonjour user1"},
{"id":"1","name":"user2","type":"ff","message":"hello user2"},
{"id":"2","name":"user3","type":"mm","message":"konnichiwa user3"},
{"id":"3","name":"user4","type":"mf","message":"ni hao user4"},
{"id":"4","name":"user5","type":"ff","message":"high 5! user5"}]}
```

I have an input named `content` and I would like to see if it matches any of the `name` in the array; if it does, which `id` is it; if it's not, the `id` would be 0. 

 Eg. if user enters user3, the `id` would be 2; and if user enters user9, the `id` would be 0.

I have been struggling to get the value of `name` from this nested array and below is what I have tried... and the whole code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/fx2q4cLg/). It would be very nice if someone could tell me where have I done wrong:

```
    var data = {};
    $.ajax({
      url: googleApi,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(googleKey + ":" + googleSecret)
      },
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',

      success: function(data) {

        console.log(data); 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 

        function getID(name){
            if (name.name == content){
            console.log ("matching name" + name.name);
            return getID(name.name);

            } else {
                return name;
            }
        }
        alert(getID(data).id);
        return false;

      },

      error: function(data) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + data);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Dont alert the function, just alert the answer inside the loop when it matched.

I typed **alexis** in the textbox and the output was **1**

I have edited my answer.Check it, this is what you have to do in your case:

```
            function getID(name) {
                $.each(data,function(key,value){

                    $.each(value,function(key1,value1){
                             console.log(value);
                           if(value1 == content){
                               alert(value.id);
                               return;
                            }
                       });
                });
            }
            getID(data);
            return false;
```

Take a look at the **updated fiddle** **[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fx2q4cLg/1/)**

**Second Update:**

You do not have to use `else if` condition, simply use a variable to check whether there has been any matches.

You create a empty variable and while looping through the array check whether there is a match and if there is a match, you just feed the variable with that `id` value and later you will check whether the variable is empty or not and based on that `alert(0);`

Checkout the **[Latest Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx2q4cLg/5/)**

Comment: Hi @Identity Unkn0wn, thanks for your suggestion. Since the array is printed from a Google API I created (which the values would change upon every update),  were you suggesting that rather than `var data = {};` I have before `$.ajax()`, I should declare it as `var data = []` ? Cheers x

Comment: hi..I just updated my answer and it seems to work,take a look

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions :))) I have been trying to print the value `id` as 0 if the input doesn't match with any of the `names` but it made the function printed the `id` as 0 even if it is not... eg. 0 for alexis when it is supposed to be 1. You may find the fiddle here please: http://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/fx2q4cLg/3/ x

Comment: Hi..checkout my answer and the fiddle, hope it makes things clear

Comment: MERCI BEAUCOUP :DDD xxx

Comment: with little help from google trnslation, Pas de problème :D

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, you can use the grep function which is intended for searching an array:

```
var contentArray = [{"id":"0","name":"user1","type":"mf","message":"bonjour user1"},
{"id":"1","name":"user2","type":"ff","message":"hello user2"},
{"id":"2","name":"user3","type":"mm","message":"konnichiwa user3"},
{"id":"3","name":"user4","type":"mf","message":"ni hao user4"},
{"id":"4","name":"user5","type":"ff","message":"high 5! user5"}];

var input = 'user5';
var result = $.grep(contentArray, function(e){ return e.name == input; });
```

The result is an array with the items found. If you know that the object is always there and that it only occurs once, you can just use `result[0].id` to get the value. Otherwise you should check the length of the resulting array. Example:

```
if (result.length === 0) {
  // not found
} else if (result.length === 1) {
  // access the name property using result[0].id
} else {
  // multiple items found
}
```

So you can design a function for above as per your requirement, something like below:

```
function getID(myArr, inputName) {
  var result = $.grep(myArr, function(e){ return e.name == inputName; });

   if (result.length === 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (result.length === 1) {
      return result[0].id
    } else {
      // multiple items found
      // May be it's not true in your case
      return result[0].id
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was trying with your code [in the link here](http://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/fx2q4cLg/4/) with the name laurence, which should print an alert of "2" but it printed "not found"... Would you kindly advise which part is wrong please? Cheers x